# Composite component with navigation using managed bean

Tags: jsf-2, navigation, managed-bean, composite-component

I created a composite component that receives a managed bean as a parameter. The composite has a submit `h:commandButton` that runs a method from the managed bean parameter (`#cc.attrs.mBean.action}`; signature: `String action()`).

Knowing about the use of the `target` attribute in `composite:implementation` if I were using a method-signature instead of a bean action: is there a way to achieve a similar behavior when using a bean method?

Other reads:
[Unable to find matching navigation case from composite component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657829/unable-to-find-matching-navigation-case-from-composite-component)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error turned out to be validation errors that were not being shown and block the execution of the methods - in conclusion, this seems to work as described in the question.